# To show a particular element is the unit of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$Problem$

Suppose that a and b belong to a commutative ring $R$ with unity. If $a$ is the unit of $R$ and $b^2 = 0$; Show that $a+b$ is a unit of $R$.

$ Attempt$

$(a+b)(a-b) a^{-2}= (a^2-b^2)a^{-2}= 1$.

How to show that $a+b$ is a unit if we replace $b^2$ with $b^n$

I have just started ring theory after finishing Group theory. 
Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ (*note: this uses the assumption that $R$ is commutative.  It is not necessarily true in general rings*)

Comment: $(a^2-b^2)a^-2= 1. I think i can solve this now.

Comment: Is this true for any power of b

Comment: If you feel the duplicate is too general, check out any of the other 18 questions linked to it. And please try the search feature first next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In general, even if you just have $b^n=0$, let $c=-a^{-1}$ and write $a+b$ as $a(1-cb)$ and $1=(1-cb)(1+cb+c^2b^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot)$, where the sum is finite because eventually the terms all vanish, so $1-cb$ as an inverse and thus so does $a+b=a(1-cb)$.

In general, when you have nilpotent elements floating around, remembering power series representations like $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot$ is very useful.